# select query result filter using if conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have folllowing select query

```
              SELECT 
              Table.ID                
              SUM(CASE WHEN Table.Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS NormalCount,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Table.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS AbnormalCount
              FROM Table                 
              GROUP BY Table.ID
```

I want to get above results and generate new result set with following conditions

```
IF(NormalCount > 0 or AbnormalCount == NULL)
              SELECT 
              Table.ID                
              Table.Status AS "Normal"
              FROM Table                 
              GROUP BY Table.ID

ELSE IF ( AbnormalCount > 0)
              SELECT 
              Table.ID      
              Table.Status AS "Abnormal"
              SUM(CASE WHEN Header.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS AbnormalCount
              FROM Table                 
              GROUP BY Table.ID
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: AbnormalCount == NULL ?? in SQL Server ?

Comment: @Aditya just use those for simulation perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic you want is to label each `ID` group as being abnormal if it has one or more abnormal observation.  If so, then you can use another `CASE` statement to check the conditional abnormal sum and label the status appropriately.  Normal groups would have the characteristic of having an abnormal count of zero, but this count would appear for all groups.

```
SELECT t.ID,
       CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            THEN "Abnormal"
            ELSE "Normal" END AS Status,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AbnormalCount
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Comment: I think You tackled my issue properly and optimum way(without going nested query) :)

Comment: if I have a requirement to show specific column set if `( AbnormalCount > 0)` else reduce the column , so my approach like exactly similar to this http://imgur.com/a/Xtu7t
what should I do

Comment: You can't make an entire column conditionally disappear without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: can you recommend to a dynamic  SQL. example  resource that kind similar to my probelm ? can I use another Select Query by including this query with IF ELSE ?

Comment: Here is a link to an intro on dynamic SQL: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/ ... try something, and if you get stuck then ask another question.